# bash: how to extract text from beginning of a string to the first number?

Tags: regex, bash, filenames

I've a bunch of files named like this:

```
text 01 (blabla) other text
text 02 (whatever) other text
.
.
text 025 (etc) other tex

some text 1 (20031020) other text
some text 2 (20031022) other text
.
.
some text 10 (20031025) other text

some new text 01 other text
.
.
.
some new text 200 other text
```

and I want to extract from the filename only the words before the first number, so from the example above I want to obtain:

```
text
some text
some new text
```

I want to do this to move each file in belonging folder depending on file name (or create the folder if it not exist).

I want to do this with bash, and I know it can be done using regex but I don't know how, I've only seen example where the field are delimited by known characters, while in this case the limit is a space followed by any number.

Comment: Do you only want unique strings like your example indicates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `${variable%%pattern}` (this remove suffix pattern).

```
$ filename='text 01 (blabla) other text'
$ echo ${filename%%[0-9]*}
text
```